# Pull json data into table view using swiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

How do I show the following code in table view using swift 2 swiftyJSON

I am new so full guide would be appreciated

I have already worked of other json open source projects but without swiftyJSON

```
  {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, just read the SwiftJSON usage part, [this is](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) the right place to start.
Just some tips shortly: 
First you need to get your json data from someone (in this case, this will come from a get request, and stored in NSData?)

1. Store your json:
   `let json = JSON(data: data!)`
2. Get the names from json and store it in `var names = [String]()`

`let count = json["employees"].count
for var i = 0; i < count; ++i 
{    let name = json["employees"][i]["firstName"].stringValue       self.names.append(name)

}`

After that you should simple use this array in UITableView delegate methods.

Comment: would you be able to create sample project then i will correct this project